# Webpack not reloading at all even on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

So what is happening is I have a Homepage with just

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<p>This is the home page!</p>
```

For example if I change `Home` to `test`, nothing happens until i restart webpack (close connection, rerun webpack -d).  So not only is hot-reloading not working, no reloading is working at all.  I dont know whats up with it, I thought I had followed all the tutorials correctly.

my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './client/src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'static', 'js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [ 'react-hot-loader/webpack', 'babel-loader' ],
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })
  ]
};
```

i'm running `webpack -d`

here is what i assume is all the important packages i'm using as well:

```
"babel-preset-node6": "^11.0.0",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.7",
"react-redux": "^5.0.5",
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"react-scripts": "^1.0.7",
"react-slick": "^0.14.11",
"redux": "^3.7.0",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-mock-store": "1.0.2",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
"sequelize": "^4.1.0",
"sequelize-cli": "^2.7.0",
"webpack": "^3.0.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
```

furthermore, I'm getting another error that i think is unrelated to the overall reloading, but is related to hot reloading and it would be helpful if someone could provide some advice:

`EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

Answer (score 0):

add

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
```

in scripts in package.json and run your app using npm start,It should refresh automatically.ue,

Install the dependency using

```
npm install webpack-dev-server --hot
```

have a look at this for your error

https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware/issues/26